# Some DataProvider public java.lang.Object[][] com.qa.tests.RegisterTest.getHXTestData(java.lang.String) parameters unresolved

Tags: data-driven-tests

I am getting following issue while getting data from excel for my Register test class. i am following a data driven approach with POM .
Console error:
[image]

Code i have written:
[image]

Comment: Please guide me .

Comment: Please update your answer by adding your code and your error as formatted text, you can refer to [ask]